# How to concatenate string in php with conditions?

Tags: php, concatenation

I wrote query in php file ,my query is:

```
$query = "SELECT cc.NAME complex_check_name,f.name server_name,
                sgk.NAME single_check_name,cc.operator 
          FROM complex_check cc, 
               lnksinglechecktocomplexcheck lk,
               single_checks sgk,
               functionalci f ,
               lnkconfigurationitemtosinglecheck lkcg 
           WHERE cc.id = lk.complex_check_id AND 
                 sgk.id = lk.single_check_id and 
                 sgk.id = lkcg.single_check_id AND 
                 lkcg.config_item_id = f.id ";

if ($result=mysqli_query($link,$query))
{
    while ($obj=mysqli_fetch_object($result))
    {
       $list= $obj->complex_check_name . 
              "@".
              $obj->server_name .
              ";". 
              $obj->single_check_name . 
              $obj-> operator;

        echo  $list .'<br>'; 
    }
 }
```

The result is :

```
test_com_check_sep01@INFRASEP01;cpu check sep01&
test_com_check_sep01@INFRASEP01;DB check sep01&
test_com_check_sep01@INFRASEP01;disk space check sep01&
test_com_check_sep02@INFRASEP02;cpu check sep02||
test_com_check_sep02@INFRASEP02;db check sep02||
test_com_check_sep02@INFRASEP02;disk space check sep02||
```

How can I  concatenate the string as:

```
"test_com_check_sep01=INFRASEP01;cpu check sep01&INFRASEP01;DBcheck sep01&INFRASEP01;disk space check sep01"

"test_com_check_sep02=INFRASEP02;cpu check sep02||INFRASEP02;db check sep02||INFRASEP02;disk space check sep02"
```

Comment: Or gather values into a separate `array` and implode.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you advice . Yes, I want to concatenate the values of "obj->server_name,$obj->single_check_name,$obj-> operator" until  the value of "$obj->complex_check_name" changes .

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you?

Comment: not yet . Because , the answers are different what I really want . What I want is to concatenate the values of "obj->server_name,$obj->single_check_name,$obj-> operator" until the value of "$obj->complex_check_name" changes .I wrote as : $flag= $obj->complex_check_name; if(strcmp($flag,$obj->complex_check_name) ) { // concatenate code is there } ,but this is not worked as I expected .How can I modify this ? thanks !

Comment: I originally answered but deleted my answer because it was not 100% correct and I had to leave. Let me take a look again at it.

Comment: Hey, nowhere in your desired outcome is the `@` symbol. Why are you putting it in your loop?

Comment: thanks . You are right . In the out come , I didn't desire "@" in the final result. but , I used the "@" as delemeter . my code is :  if ($result=mysqli_query($link,$query))
   {
    while ($obj=mysqli_fetch_object($result))
   {
    $list= $obj->complex_check_name . "@".$obj->server_name .";". $obj->single_check_name . $obj-> operator;
     $result_list[] =  $list; 
   }
   //echo $final_res_list_A ;
   }   , then I used the following code : $res_tem = explode('@',$result_list[$lineCounter]);
    $complex_check_name = $res_tem[0];
    $result .= " " . $res_tem[1]; . Thanks !

Comment: Ok see if my undeleted answer comes close. I am just doing it in my mind, I haven't tried to run it....

Comment: It is not problem . I just want to get the idea how can I concatenate the values of "obj->server_name,$obj->single_check_name,$obj-> operator" until the value of "$obj->complex_check_name" changes .If there is some error in your code, I will modify the code . I really appreciate for you help !

Comment: Well let me know how it works, I am interested to see if I came close with it.

Comment: $query = "SELECT cc.NAME complex_check_name,f.name server_name,sgk.NAME single_check_name,cc.operator FROM complex_check cc,lnksinglechecktocomplexcheck lk,single_checks sgk, functionalci f ,lnkconfigurationitemtosinglecheck lkcg WHERE cc.id = lk.complex_check_id AND sgk.id = lk.single_check_id and sgk.id = lkcg.single_check_id AND lkcg.config_item_id = f.id ";
 if ($result=mysqli_query($link,$query))
   { while ($obj=mysqli_fetch_object($result))
   { $list= $obj->complex_check_name . "@".$obj->server_name .";". $obj->single_check_name . $obj-> operator;
     $result_list[] =  $list; } }

Comment: with  the code above,we can get all rows as an object , and then concatenate values of each column and save it in the array  $result_list[] .

Comment: But, still I don't know how to concatenate the values of "obj->server_name,$obj->single_check_name,$obj-> operator" until the value of "$obj->complex_check_name" changes .I really appreciate for your help ! thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the values into an array and implode afterwards.

```
$check  =   array();
if($result = mysqli_query($link,$query)) {
        while($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
            // If value is not stored in check array proceed
            if(!in_array($obj->complex_check_name,$check))
                $list[$obj->complex_check_name][]   =   $obj->complex_check_name."=";

            $list[$obj->complex_check_name][]   =   $obj->server_name.";".$obj->single_check_name.$obj->operator;

            // Store in check array
            $check[]    =   $obj->complex_check_name;
        }

    // Loop through stored rows and implode with break
    foreach($list as $array) {
            echo implode("<br />",$array);
        }
 }
```

Comment: Maybe mark off the answer as correct so no one comes to try and solve your problem when it's already been solved.

Comment: yes, you are right. I need to mark off the answer as correct . I tried to mark off the answer as correct . But,I could not find where I can do that . Thanks !

Comment: Thanks ! the problem is solved by @Rasclatt suggestion . Thanks a lot !

Comment: Beside the answer should be a blank check mark,  click it and it should go green

Comment: Ok, yes I did that the question was already answered . Thanks a lot ! have a nice day !

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$concat1 = '';
$concat2 = '';
if ($result=mysqli_query($link,$query))
  {
      while ($obj=mysqli_fetch_object($result))
        {
           if($obj->server_name == 'INFRASEP01'){
                concat1 .= $obj->complex_check_name . "@".$obj->server_name .";". $obj->single_check_name . $obj-> operator;
           }else{
                concat2 .= $obj->complex_check_name . "@".$obj->server_name .";". $obj->single_check_name . $obj-> operator;
           }
        }
   }
echo  $concat1 .'<br>'.$concat2;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you advice . Yes, I want to concatenate the values of "obj->server_name,$obj->single_check_name,$obj-> operator" until the value of "$obj->complex_check_name" changes .                                                                              each row is consisted of "$obj->complex_check_name,obj->server_name,$obj->single_check_name,$obj-> operator" . And I want to concatenate the values of "obj->server_name,$obj->single_check_name,$obj-> operator" until the value of "$obj->complex_check_name" changes . ok , I will try . Thanks again for your advice !

Comment: In value of "$obj->server_name " always changes.it is not just " INFRASEP01, INFRASEP02" . to concatenate the values of "obj->server_name,$obj->single_check_name,$obj-> operator" until the value of "$obj->complex_check_name" changes , I wrote like : $flag= $obj->complex_check_name;  if(strcmp($flag,$obj->complex_check_name) )
     {
   // concatenate code is there    
     } ,but this is not worked as I expected . How can I modify this code to concatenate the values of "obj->server_name,$obj->single_check_name,$obj-> operator" until the value of "$obj->complex_check_name" changes ,please ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to keep the lines separate for use, you could do this

```
$list = array("INFRASEP01", "INFRASEP01", "INFRASEP02");
$concatINFRASEP01 = "";
$concatINFRASEP02 = "";
for($lineCounter = 0; $lineCounter < sizeof($list); $lineCounter++)
    if(strpos($list[$lineCounter], "INFRASEP01") !== false){
        //Found it
        $concatINFRASEP01 .= " " . $list[$lineCounter];
    }
    else if(strpos($list[$lineCounter], "INFRASEP02") !== false){
        $concatINFRASEP02 .= " " . $list[$lineCounter];
    }
```

NOTE: I did not test this code so there may be errors.

If you do not need the $list array, then you can do as @Malakiof suggested.

**EDIT (01/22/2015):** I have improved my answer but left the old one there in case I misunderstood.

```
//In your case the rows come from the $obj (which most would call $row)
$listOfRows = array("test_com_check_sep01@INFRASEP01;cpu check sep01&","test_com_check_sep01@INFRASEP01;DB check sep01&", "test_com_check_sep02@INFRASEP02;cpu check sep02||");

//Create this array as you go through each row by adding the server_name
//to this array. You can skip making this array and simply make the
//unique array by checking if the array contains the server_name.
$listServerNames = array("INFRASEP01","INFRASEP02","INFRASEP01", "INFRASEP02", "INFRASEP01");

//Only have unique server names to avoid duplicates
$listUniqueServerNames = array_unique($listServerNames);

//this will be your list of concatenated strings
$concatByServerName = array();

//Go through the unique server names one by one
foreach($listUniqueServerNames as $serverName)
//While looking at each unique server name, look through the rows
foreach($listOfRows as $line)
if(strpos($line, $serverName) !== false){
    //Found it
if(array_key_exists($serverName, $concatByServerName))
    $concatByServerName[$serverName] .= " " . $line;
else
    $concatByServerName[$serverName] = $line;
}
```

If the $listOfRows is very large, consider making a copy of $listOfRows and removing the lines from $listOfRows when you add them to $concatByServerName.

Although this is not the best way to do it, I am trying to keep it simple in order for you to be able to get it to work, while fully understanding what is happening. You can easily improve on this code by looking at your project and streamlining these tasks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you advice . Yes, I want to concatenate the values of "obj->server_name,$obj->single_check_name,$obj-> operator" until the value of "$obj->complex_check_name" changes .                                                                              each row is consisted of "$obj->complex_check_name,obj->server_name,$obj->single_check_name,$obj-> operator" . And I want to concatenate the values of "obj->server_name,$obj->single_check_name,$obj-> operator" until the value of "$obj->complex_check_name" changes . ok , I will try . Thanks again for your advice !

Comment: In value of "$obj->server_name " always changes.it is not just " INFRASEP01, INFRASEP02" . to concatenate the values of "obj->server_name,$obj->single_check_name,$obj-> operator" until the value of "$obj->complex_check_name" changes , I wrote like : $flag= $obj->complex_check_name;  if(strcmp($flag,$obj->complex_check_name) )
     {
   // concatenate code is there    
     } ,but this is not worked as I expected . How can I modify this code to concatenate the values of "obj->server_name,$obj->single_check_name,$obj-> operator" until the value of "$obj->complex_check_name" changes ,please ?

Comment: You need to decide what rules dictate which row belongs to which concatenated string. The example I wrote assumed all of the same Server Name would be concatenated together. What are your rules? I will improve my answer and hopefully it will help you.